# Powershell v2.0 substitute null values from a Hash table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have a hash table as below:

```
$Hash = @{
Team1=$Team1.count
Team2=$Team2.count
Team3=$Team3.count
} 

$GroupByTeam = New-Object psobject -Property $Hash | 
Select 'Team1','Team2','Team3' | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

This is fine and each "team" returns their own value. However, teams may have a null value and I wish to substitute this for "0".

In an attempt to work this out, I have tried to select the null value first but can't seem to do this:

```
$Hash.values | select -property Values 

Values
------
{1, 2}
```

But

```
$Hash.values | select -property Values | where {$_.Values is $null}
```

doesn't pull back anything. Also tried:

```
$Hash.values | select -expandproperty Values | where {$_.Values is $null}
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to cast the values to `int` when creating the hashtable:

```
$Hash = @{
  Team1 = [int]$Team1.Count
  Team2 = [int]$Team2.Count
  Team3 = [int]$Team3.Count
}
```

If that's not possible for some reason you could go with an enumerator:

```
($Hash.GetEnumerator()) | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.Value -eq $null) { $Hash[$_.Name] = 0 }
}
```

or (as [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38306101/1630171) suggested) use the `Keys` property to the same end:

```
($Hash.Keys) | ForEach-Object {
  if ($Hash[$_] -eq $null) { $Hash[$_] = 0 }
}
```

Note that either way you need to use a subexpression (or assign the enumerated objects/keys to a variable) otherwise you'll get an error because you're modifying a data structure while it's being enumerated.

Answer (score 2):

What you'll want to do is collect the `keys` that refer to null values, and then populate those with `0`s:

```
# Create and populate hashtable
$HashTable = @{
    Team1 = 123
    Team2 = $null
    Team3 = 456
}

# Find keys of `$null` values
$nullKeys = $HashTable.Keys |Where-Object { $HashTable[$_] -eq $null }

# Populate appropriate indices with 0
$nullKeys |ForEach-Object { $HashTable[$_] = 0 }
```